# How to find: Boldest font readable at a small size?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, readability

I'm not sure how to communicate this to the various font search engines online. I want something that is going to be extremely bold, like as bold as possible, so bold it almost spills out of the glyph. But extremely readable at a regular copy size (12pt Arial).

I've tried

- bold
- sans-serif
- readable
- poster
- display

But I feel like I am missing something obvious to search for just from not having much industry knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fat** fonts, **Wide** fonts, **Extended** fonts, **Expanded** fonts

[image: FAT WIDE EXTENDED EXPANDED]

If you are looking for legibility at small size, Google "maximum x-height fonts".

[Tusker Grotesk](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lewis-mcguffie-type/tusker-grotesk/) is one of the results, this capture is at 11pt according to myfonts.

[image: tusker]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, weights thicker then 'bold' are either called 'extra bold', 'black' or 'heavy', so look up any family that would include these super bold weights. One that I have used extensively is [Axiforma](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/kastelov/axiforma/) which includes these things.

[image]